# Money expiration tracking

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, currency

I am working with money expiration tracking problem at the moment (originally it is not money, but I have used it as a more convenient example).

An user can earn money from a platform for some mysterious reason and spent them for buying stuff (products, gifts etc.).

**I am looking an algorithm (SQL query best case) to find a current balance of an user balance.**

The events of spending and earning money are stored different database (*MySQL*) tables (let's say `user_earned` and `user_spent`). So in normal case, I would simply count user totals from `user_earned` and subtract spent money (total of `user_spent`).

BUT! There is a condition, that **earned user money expires in 2 years** if they are not used.
That means, if user have not used his money or used just a part of it, they will expire. If an user uses his money, they are used from the **oldest not expired money record**, so the balance (bonus) could be calculated in user's favor.

These are 5 scenarios with events in time, to have a better understanding on the case:

[image: Money expiration logic]

Both tables (`user_earned` and `user_spent`) have *timestamps* for date tracking.

Comment: This may be a task that is best done in application code.

Comment: Currently, I have implemented a service, which calculates the balance by simply building a list of events (receiving, usage, expiration) and running them one by one. It works, but in case I needed to the balance in a SQL query to get users with positive balance, I would have to denormalize this value before to the Database.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in one of my projects.

Looks like you need an additional table `spends_covering` with columns
`spend_id`, `earhed_id`, `sum`

So for each `spends` record you need to insert one or many rows into the `spends_covering` to mark 'used' money.

Then balance would be just sum of not used where date is less than 2 years.

```
select sum(sub.earned_sum-sub.spent_sum) as balance
from
    (select e.sum as earned_sum, sum(sc.sum) as spent_sum 
    from earned e
         left join spends_covering sc on e.earhed_id=sc.earhed_id
    where e.date BETWEEN ...
    group by e.earhed_id
    having earned_sum > spent_sum) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth it to have two tables -- one (or more) with all the historical details, one with just the current balances for each 'user'.  Be sure to  use transactions to keep the two in sync.